# unable to launch Google calendar ics file attachment

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gmail, calendar, google, attachments

I received an gmail from my sons baseball coach with a Google calendar ics   attachment file for the seasons schedule. When I click on the attachment in the email while on my Alcatel onetouch FierceXL it says unable to launch event.  Then when I went to gmail on my huawei union,opened the email, & clicked on the attachment it downloaded and worked. My alcatel onetouch FierceXL is my main phone I don't understand why it won't work on it? I'm not very electronically minded and am lost when it comes to trying to navigate phones & computers or understand what the meaning of things are. Is there something I need to do to  be able to open the attachment and work on my alcatel?

Comment: I also have this problem. I saw on the google forum that google provided a fix for Calendar ver 5.1 I now have calendar 5.5.2 and it don't work.
Bob